LinkedIn API UploadUrl
I am currently working with LinkedIn's API to obtain an uploadUrl for images and videos. However, I've noticed that the format of the returned uploadUrl varies inconsistently. Here are the two different styles of URLs I receive:

https://api.linkedin.com/mediaUpload/sp/sync/{id}/uploaded-image/0?ca=vector_feedshare&cn=uploads&app={appId}&sync=1&v=beta&ut={ut}

https://www.linkedin.com/dms-uploads/sp/sync/{id}/uploaded-image/0?ca=vector_feedshare&cn=uploads&sync=1&v=beta&ut={ut}
This issue began occurring after I was granted access to the "Advertising API" product.


I am using Spring's OpenFeign client to send the requests. Below is the relevant part of the code:
String getUploadUrl(
    @RequestBody String body,
    @RequestHeader("Authorization") String bearerToken
);

//The configurations in my .properties file are:
linkedInApi.name=linkedInApiRequests
linkedInApi.domain-url=https://api.linkedin.com
linkedInApi.get-upload-url=/v2/assets?action=registerUpload


//Here is how I call the OpenFeign method:
linkedInApiClient.getUploadUrl(String.format(LINKED_IN_GET_UPLOADING_JSON, postingRequest.getClientUrn(), postingRequest.getContentType()), "Bearer " + postingRequest.getAccessToken());

//The content type can be either image or video. 
//Below is the LINKED_IN_GET_UPLOADING_JSON constant:
{
  "registerUploadRequest":{
    "owner":"urn:li:person:%s",
    "recipes":[
      "urn:li:digitalmediaRecipe:feedshare-%s"
    ],
    "serviceRelationships":[
      {
        "identifier":"urn:li:userGeneratedContent",
        "relationshipType":"OWNER"
      }
    ],
    "supportedUploadMechanism":[
      "SYNCHRONOUS_UPLOAD"
    ]
  }
}

When I send the same request using Postman, it always returns the first style of uploadUrl.
I am looking for insights into why there might be such discrepancies in the API response and how I can stabilize the format of the returned URL.
Any suggestions or explanations would be highly appreciated. Thank you!
